# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

The problem Im facing while trying to connect to database for mysql. I have also given the database settings that i have used.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/home/arundhati/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.db import models
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
return import_module('.base', backend_name)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/ar/Desktop/test/testprac/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Databse Settings::

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'ar_test_db',                      # Or path to database file if using 
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or   '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help !!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the python mysql package installed, try:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

or if not using a virtual environment (on *nix hosts):

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? I recommend you do just to keep things organized. If that's not an option then you'll need to run pip with superuser privileges:

    sudo pip install mysql-python

Comment: I am using virtual env, and i have installed mysql, django... however when i do python manage.py syncdb
It gives me the same error that i have posted

Comment: do i have a version problem by any chance? I am using django 1.5 , python 2.7.3 with my sql(14.14 for debian)

Comment: This solve for me: 

Activate my environment
# source bin/activate     

Then install it as a package
# sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: with python 3 is: pip install mysqlclient

Comment: This in python3 not works. requires ConfigParser which is not available in python3

Comment: @getitstarted, If you you use macos + homebrew and still see the error –– check your openssl symlinks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Answer (score 50):

If you get errors trying to install mysqlclient with pip, you may lack the mysql dev library. Install it by running:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and try again to install mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: It was `pip install mysqlclient`. I had forgotten to add this to my requirements.txt file, so even though the MySQL database was there and populated, my Django web server couldn't interact with it.

Comment: thanks this answer saved my day i have been trying to make mysql work with django for 2 days :)

Comment: This was the real problem for me. Installing libmysqlclient-dev first allowed me to install mysqlclient inside the environment, and then proceed with the migration. Thank you "Psddp"!

Comment: all checked many solutions for django 4.x. just your way: apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev  worked very good.

Answer (score 41):

You have to install `python-mysqldb` - Python interface to MySQL.

Try:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 14):

My answer is similar to @Ron-E, but I got a few more errors/corrections so I'm putting my steps below for Mac OSX on Mavericks and Python 2.7.6.

1. Install Python mysql package (if you get a success message, then ignore the below steps)

   ```
   pip install mysql-python
   ```
2. When I did the above, I got the error "EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found"
       [image]
       To fix this, I did the below in terminal:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
   ```
3. When I reran step 1, I get a new error "error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1"
   [image]
       To fix this, I did the below in terminal:

   ```
    export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
    export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
   ```
4. I reran step 1 and got the success message 'Successfully installed mysql-python'!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I got first of your problem.

Comment: I have followed your way but first error is always occurring in my case.
And  for  ` export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
`  terminal is giving that error: `-bash: export: =-Qunused-arguments': not a valid identifier
`

Comment: this worked for me after hours of trying -- don't know why this isn't the highest voted answer. Another thing to do is to make sure you're on the right version of MySQL

Answer (score 12):

When I set up Django development environment for PyCharm in Mac OS X Mountain Lion with python, mysql, sequel pro application I got error same as owner of this thread.
However, my answer for them who is running python-mysqldb under Mac OS Mountain Lion x86_x64 (MySql and Python also should be same architecture) and already tried everything like pip and etc. In order fix this problem do following steps:

1. Download MySql for Python from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)
2. Untar downloaded file. In terminal window do following: tar xvfz downloade.tar.
3. cd /to untared directory
4. Run sudo python setup.py install
5. If you get error something like this: "Environment Error: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config not found" then try to add path ass follows: "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin". But id did not helped to me and I found another solution. In the end of command execution error output which looks like this:

   File "/path_to_file/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
   raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
6. Open setup_posix.py with vim and go to line 25 (In your case it can be different unless if it is same version).
7. Line 25 should look like this after your editing unless your mysql have symbolic link like follows '/usr/local/mysql/bin/':

   `f = popen("%s --%s" % ('/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config', what))`
8. After this I got another error as following:

   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
   Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
   Reason: image not found
9. Finally I did following in console:

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Currently everything works fine. So I hope it will be helpful for somebody who uses Mac. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It took me almost a week just to run my first project using mysql haha. Phew...

Comment: Thanks a ton man! you saved my day! i was using mac and getting same problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Python version 3.4 or above, you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

in your terminal. Then install `pip install mysqlclient` on your virtual env or where you installed pip.

Answer (score 9):

I've **solved** this issue in this environment:

```
$ pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.9

$ python --version
Python 3.7.2

$ python -m django --version
2.1.7
```

***./settings.py***

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'my_db_name',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',   # 'django.db.backends.mysql'
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pass>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

If you use `'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django'` , install driver executing:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.15 protobuf-3.7.0 six-1.12.0
```

**Note that `$ pip install mysql-python`didn't work for me.**

Note that if you use  `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'` , you should install driver executing:
`$ pip install mysqlclient`

Finally execute:
`$ python manage.py migrate`

If it's all right, python creates all these tables id database:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_migrations
django_session
```

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

I used 'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django' with pip3 install mysql-connector-python

It still didn't work

Answer (score 8):

You are missing the python `mysqldb` library. Use this command (for Debian/Ubuntu) to install it:
`sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: This is an answer, but I think it would be great if you could add more details than a single line. Thanks!

Comment: Above command help us to install the Python interface to the MySQL database.

Answer (score 8):

It is because it did not find sql connector. try:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 6):

Download and install Mysql-python from here for windows environment.  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python.

Comment: I use this, and I dont' install mysql my machine

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 or python 3 versions

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu it is advised to use the distributions repository.

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I recommend to use it in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

With the same error message as Will, it worked for me to install mysql first as the missing file will be added during the installation.
So after

```
brew install mysql

pip install mysql-python
```

ran without errors.

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/yn/nrq74lgs6kqdzcr035p_5g280000gn/T/pip-build-jwQcm5/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/yn/nrq74lgs6kqdzcr035p_5g280000gn/T/pip-UmTWRJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yn/nrq74lgs6kqdzcr035p_5g280000gn/T/pip-build-jwQcm5/mysql-python/

Answer (score 2):

This happened with me as well and I believe this has become a common error not only for Django developers but also for Flask as well, so the way I solved this issue was using brew.

1. `brew install mysql`
2. `sudo pip install mysql-python`

This way every single issue was solved and both frameworks work absolutely fine.

P.S.: For those who use macports (such as myself), this can be an issue as brew works in a different level, my advice is to use brew instead of macports

I hope I could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.The following solved my issue

Run `pip install pymysql` in your shell

Then, edit the `init.py` file in your project origin directory (the same as `settings.py`)
and then

add:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

this should solve the problem.

Comment: "Then, edit init.py file in your project origin directory" - do you mean `__init__.py` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the version error.

try installing this in following order:

1. `sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb`
2. `pip3 install mysqlclient`
3. `python3 manage.py makemigrations`
4. `python3 manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

**I faced this similar error to when I wanted to use MySQL as the default database.**
These error might be as a result of the fact that [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) hasn't been installed.
And this can be installed from the command line using;
`pip install mysqlclient`  (for recent versions of python)
or   `pip install mysql-python` (for older versions of python)
**In my case, after meeting this requirement, I still had this same error and it was solved as below;**
In your *django project directory*, ***select venv directory*** and under these directory,
select the ***pyvenv.cfg*** file and click allow on the dialog box which ask you if you want to edit this file.  In this file,
`include-system-site-packages` is set to `false`. So change this line of code to true like this;

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Everything now works well

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in this for a very long and then I realized what's wrong django checks for mysqlclient if it's not installed before django it throws this error so simple solution is

```
pip uninstall django
pip install mysqlclient
pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers, if you're using Django, it is advisable that you install mysql-python BEFORE installing Django.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time on this. Turns out that the default database library is not supported for Python 3. [You have to use a different one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152201/django-1-8-throwing-importerror-no-module-named-mysqldb).

Answer (score 0):

if the error looks like this

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

then try :

```
pip install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue. I tried installing `mysql-python` using pip, but it failed due to gcc dependency errors.

The solution that worked for me

```
conda install mysql-python
```

Please note that I already had anaconda installed, which didn't had gcc dependency.

Comment: could you elaborate on it

Answer (score 0):

try this, simply using pip:
On Windows the recommended command is:

```
python -m pip install mysqlclient
```

use it in a virtual environment

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read [answer], and avoid posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried running different commands in this question. However none of them work for me in MXLinux. It's a Debian 11 based distro (As of writing this). So, this answer should be applicable to Debian also.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then install mysql in your python environment

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I have tested this against, Python==3.8.13. AFAIK, this will work with Pyenv, Conda, Pipenv, Poetry etc. too.

Note:- This may work with Latest Version of Debian Based distros like LinuxMint, KDE Neon, Zorin OS, Kubuntu, elementary OS, Pop!_OS, Linux Lite, Linuxfx, etc. too.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem and located the problem to be an improperly installed mysqlclient. Installation of mysqlclient on Windows using the pip channel was causing dependency issues.
Install mysqlclient with the command:

```
> pip install mysqlclient
```

If that doesn't work, install just the mysqlclient binaries. This seemed to work for me.

```
> pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

Following is how my **./projectName/settings.py** looks.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
},
```

If you are going to use mysql-connector for the engine, then install the mysql-connector using

```
> pip install mysql-connector-python
```

And change the 'ENGINE' of DATABASES in the settings.py file to 'mysql.connector.django'.

I recommend all of the pip installations using a virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)

Install (if not found):

```
pip install mysql.connector
```

Settings:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': '...',
    'HOST': '...',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': '...',
    'PASSWORD': '...',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and try again to install mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution is already provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365315/5320906), and others in this Q&A.  When answering old questions please ensure your answer provides a unique and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try the following mode of operation:
`sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`