# Django 1.8 : Throwing ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, django, centos

I am trying to run my Django Server with python 3.4.3 and have been scratching my head on this for a while. The commands I have tried so far, and their error messages, are:

```
pip3.4 install MySQLdb (No matching distribution found for mysqldb)

pip3.4 install mysql-python (ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser')

pip3.4 install configparser
pip install ConfigParser
File "/tmp/pip-build-mcfc7tj3/ConfigParser/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

pip3.4 install mysqlclient

File "/tmp/pip-build-s41j0x_s/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found


sudo yum install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
No package python3-dev available.
No package libmysqlclient-dev available.
```

but still cannot get it installed. What should I do from here?

Notes:

Running python3.4 manage.py runserver threw

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Comment: Did you try python3.4 manage.py runserver?

Comment: MySQLdb is not supported on Python 3.4 - you need to use an [alternative driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid further down the commands you can see that the OP tries to install `mysqlclient` which should work with Python 3. The problem is that they don't have the required development libraries installed for Python 3 and mysql. I'm not familiar with CentOS, so I don't know what the correct package names are.

Comment: @Alasdair I totally didn't see that ... You're right maybe, probably issue with centos.

Comment: Thank you! I am using CentOS 7 by the way, hence the yum command

Answer (score 3):

MySQLdb is not supported on Python 3.4 - you need to use an [alternative driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

`python-dev` and `mysql-dev` are package names for the apt package system; which is used by debian, ubuntu and its clones/variants.

On CentOS you need the rpm-equivalent packages.

You should install `mysql-devel` for the MySQL development headers; you also need to have a development toolchain - the easiest way to install that is to issue `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`.

Now, if you installed Python using yum as well, you need to install `python-devel`.

Comment: Hello, I am still getting the same error from above.

Comment: I got my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224807/what-is-pymysql-and-how-does-it-differ-from-mysqldb-can-it-affect-django-deploy by editing manage.py