# Do I still need to install MySQL in Django virtual env while I already have MySQL in my machine?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have already install mysql 5.1 on my windows 10 machine , and I can connect mysql from  python by :

```
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='MYSQLTB',db='shfuture')
```

then I download django frame and try to use it to connect mysql  ,  what I do is :

create a my.cnf file content is :

```
[client]
database = shfuture
host = localhost
user = root
password = MYSQLTB
default-character-set = utf8
```

change settings.py to :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my.cnf'),
        },
    }
}
```

then run :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but got a error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install the MySQL client?
```

Do I still need to install an addition MySQL in Django virtual env?  if I can use the existing MySQL instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312732/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-mo)

Comment: You will need to install the client libraries to access a MySQL server, but not the MySQL server itself. Your question does not distinguish between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.You need to install 'mysqlclient' package or 'mysql-connector-python' package, with pip.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you dont have `mysqlclient` python library installed in virtual environment.

Since you are using Windows, you need to download and install `mysqlclient` python library from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to reinstall the mysql for django in the virtual environment again. For windows you can do:-

pip install django mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to put the following code on top of both `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
# rest of the code
```

Also you need to ensure you have `pymysql` installed in your virtual environment.

**FYI:** Using pymysql might not work in **django>=2.2** properly. You will find some solution which might work, like mentioned in [**`this ticket`**](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/790#issuecomment-489318466). Also, django does not support pymysql as mysql connector officially(ticket [**`#12500`**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12500), [**`#22391`**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22391)).

Answer (score 0):

Both *PyMySQL* and *MySQLdb* are db connectors. I assume that your django framework by default searches for MySQLdb and throws exception because it couldn't find one.

You can either install MySQLdb or follow @ruddra's answer on that. I would recommend you to go with @ruddra's answer incase of development machine. Because there are lot of issues you might(50/50 chances) face while installing and making MySQLdb to work properly.

Read [What is PyMySQL and how does it differ from MySQLdb? Can it affect Django deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224807/what-is-pymysql-and-how-does-it-differ-from-mysqldb-can-it-affect-django-deploy) to understand more on this.