# Error starting DJango server when installing Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just started to create a new project with Django.

I have installed MySql and MySql client for Python.
But this error happens when I try to run the server.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb



ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
........
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?``
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312732/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-mo

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I needed to use install the mysqlDB with python3.
But now this error appears.
Someone?

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required;

you have 1.3.10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql-client, not mysql-python.

Try to install [mysql-client](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)  and you will find many mysql-client wheels.

- Download the first one, do not change the name of the file
- open command prompt
- use cd to go to the directory where your wheel has been installed
- then use `pip install (name of file) #use .whl` as well

if it doesn't work, download the second one and repeat the process, if that doesn't work as well, keep on downloading until I guarantee you that at least one of them would be installed in your computer