# Error loading MySQLdb module - Python 3.7 on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django

After changing database to mysql in Django I cannot migrate.
I use Django 3.0.8, Python 3.7,

I have installed mysqlclient, PyMySQL, mysql-connector-python and nothing changed.

error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

Do you have any idea guys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312732/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-mo)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site, [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient), when you download the first one, go to command prompt, and use `pip install (wheel file name)`. if it doesn't work, keep on downloading the others and installing them until no error is being shown.
.

Comment: I have already installed mysqlclient and nothing changed.

Comment: Then I bet there's a new problem here